# How to assign a name to running container in docker?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, boot2docker

I have created container from particular image using command:

```
$ docker run -d -P selenium/hub
```

running container status is below:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                    STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
345df9ed5b47        selenium/hub        "/opt/bin/entry_point"   5 seconds ago              Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:32768->4444/tcp   clever_williams
```

Here default name is "clever_williams" and I forgot to assign new name to it
I need to change default name to running container so how can I do that?

Comment: If you are really struck, you may wipe it out and run again within seconds with new name.

Comment: I can do that, but I want to know how to do that while containers are running!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check the [`docker rename`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rename/) command, it works for either a running or stopped container, the pattern is:

```
docker rename old_name new_name
```

Therefore according with your provided data it can be:

```
docker rename clever_williams new_name
```

(This is for docker 1.10+, from [PR 8570](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/8570))

Comment: For the audience, this command works for a container stopped too.

Comment: Just in case to avoid confusions for the audience - I think the correct command to show is `docker rename clever_williams new_name`, old name to new name - but you are using the container's id as the first argument. It is not reflected in the _current_ `docker rename` reference documentation. As I see your answer was written at 2016 ... I am assuming the doc was updated.

Comment: @ManuelJordan true, don't hesitate to edit this answer with your update.

Comment: Thanks to you for the confirmation and green light to edit! :)